# Way to "preload" Canvas animation before showing the page?

Tags: android, jquery, canvas, webview, createjs

I have started experimenting with the WebView in order to display locally stored HTML files that play some fairly basic Canvas animations (using the CreateJS library).

They seem to play really well but some times, the page is loading and playing the animation before images are fully loaded (e.g. one animation has a fairly large background image ~1mb)

Is there a way to either "speed" things up, "preload/prefetch" the images (and other assets if need be) or simply wait till the app has loaded the images into its memory (if it does that) before displaying and starting the animation?

To add to that last question, is there a way to "pause" the animation and only play it once the images have fully loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with onload event which runs after all images or external resources are loaded:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  //code
});
```

or you can try with  load event for individual images and run your code when they have loaded:

```
$('img.imgClass').load(function(){
  // The image loaded,,, code 
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the incoming stupid question, but this is to be included in my javascript code, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The CreateJS suite includes PreloadJS, which is a pretty decent way of preloading content that is used by EaselJS, or any other content for that matter.
http://preloadjs.com

You can pre-fetch images, javascript, audio, JSON/text/XML, SVG, CSS, etc.

```
var queue = new createjs.PreloadJS();
queue.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
queue.loadManifest([
    {id: "image", src:"image.png"},
    {id: "image2", src: "image2.jpg"},
    {id:"script", src:"script.js"}
]);

function handleComplete(event) {
    var image = queue.getResult("image"); // Returns an image tag
}
```

There are some workarounds to preload audio (with multiple formats), or use tag loading to get around cross-domain issues. Check out the docs for more:
http://www.createjs.com/Docs/PreloadJS/modules/PreloadJS.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:
create a function that should do this:

```
    loadData();

loadData = function()
{
preloader = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);
        preloader.addEventListener("complete",this.handleComplete.bind(this));

        var manifest = [

            {src:"./images/yourIMAGE.PNG"},

        ];


        preloader.loadManifest(manifest);
    };


    handleComplete = function()
    {
        console.log("Load complete!");
       //other function
    };


}
```

This is a way to do it. If you have questions just let me know.

Comment: The way @Lanny did this is not actual any more. So you can not use **createjs.PreloadJS();**